# How can I replace com.sun.tools.javac.file.BaseFileObject?

Tags: java, javac

I'm trying to update a Java 7 project to Java 11, but I can't find a replacement for BaseFileObject

It's used in a scripting engine in a server for Aion, a MMORPG : https://github.com/AionGermany/aion-germany/blob/master/AL-Commons/src/com/aionemu/commons/scripting/impl/javacompiler/BinaryClass.java

If you want some example of the scripts used, they're all here : https://github.com/AionGermany/aion-germany/tree/master/AL-Game/data/scripts/system/handlers

Did Oracle put a neat replacement for it, or they just removed it entirely ?

Comment: You may just implement the underlying interface with the needed fields/methods: https://github.com/fiji/javac/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sun/tools/javac/file/BaseFileObject.java

Comment: But I would still depend on java 7

Comment: The underlying interface JavaFileObject still exists in the JDK11?

Comment: The only thing I can find is that : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/com/sun/tools/javac/package-summary.html

Comment: Only the main is here